# HttpClient request with x509 Certificate works on Debug but fails in Production (403 forbidden)

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, dotnet-httpclient

I have a black box service I have to call into with simple rest commands that returns xml.

They issued us a certificate that had to be run in IE and installs in to IE's Certificate section. As per their instructions I exported it with the entire chain as a pfx with password.

On the machine that the cert was issued directly to, everything works fine in code

```
        var certHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
        certHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;            
        certHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Properties.Resources.SigningCert, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet); //Must be renewed and replaced every year.
        certHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);            

        //Execute the command            
        var client = new HttpClient(certHandler);
        string result;
        try
        {
            result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

(I've stored the cert in the resources, but it loads fine and loading it from a file works fine too in developer machine.)  I also imported it into IE on the server just in case. Obviously this is likely under the wrong cert store, but I couldn't figure out how to load this in globally.  I can tell you that the same REST GETs work in IE on the server just like they do on the developer machine. It's only in code that it fails.)

In production, this same code throws a 403 forbidden.

Production (really a beta server) is actually behind the same nat as the as the development machine so they're seeing the same IP come through etc.

Any ideas why it would fail on the server and not on the developer box?

Thanks!

Comment: In the machine where everything works, have you made sure the same certificate doesn't exist in other stores?

Comment: As far as I can tell it doesn't exist anywhere else. Using the winhttpcertcfg tool to do it on a clean machine however throws an not allowed error on the key and it won't import that way nor will it allow me to set permissions on it using the tool with the same error message. The 'net says that this is because the user that created the pfx must be the one to do this, but that's not possible on a remote machine obviously because it doesn't have the same users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `X509KeyStorageFlags` according to account under which your app is running. If it is

1) An app that runs under regular Windows User Account you should use

```
X509Certificate2(Properties.Resources.SigningCert, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
```

2) Windows Service under LocalSystem, IIS under NetworkService or other services under built in Windows Account, you should use

```
X509Certificate2(Properties.Resources.SigningCert, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Basically, you shouldn't use `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` in your case - you import certificate from pfx format every time.

Certificate's private key is storing in the container according to flags. So you may have no access to it if you use wrong flags.
`DefaultKeySet` is not just alias for `UserKeySet` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags(v=vs.110).aspx)) - so choose appropriate flags in every case.

These articles also may be helpfull:

1. [Key Storage and Retrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [Eight tips for working with X.509 certificates in .NET](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2)
3. [How Certificates Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776447(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is that for whatever reason it won't allow you to grant permissions properly to the key. To work around it, I went to:

X:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

In explorer and found the key in question (I used deduction by Date but the thumbprint is there so you should be able to match it up.) and then right clicked, took over the file permissions and then set the permissions manually.

Then my code just started working.

Interestingly however, on another machine that I needed to deploy this to, the file doesn't exist in the machinekeys directory so I don't know what I'm going to do there but...